# Turning an Xpath into a list variable and use For loop

Tags: list, xpath, robotframework

I'm very new to robot framework. This question is about creating a list variable using Xpath.

I'm trying to write a FOR LOOP in robot in order to print all items that appear on a search result page. Here is what I've done so far:

1. I tried to declare a list variable using Xpath:

```
    @{product}         //div[contains(@class,'ProductCard__TitleMaxLines')]
```

This Xpath has the number of repetitions the same as the number of items on the page, e.g. 20, so I assume that this list will contain 20 members. --> *Is this how it works?*

2. I created a For loop:

```
    ${index}        Set variable        1
    For     ${product}  in      @{related_product}
            Exit for loop if    ${index} > 20
            Log to console      ${product}
            ${index}        Evaluate        ${index}+1

    End
```

For this, I assume that it will take the first product found on the Xpath to be index=1, and the next index=2, and so on.

That's all I've done so far. Please advise if this works correctly or if there is another way that is better and more typical.

Comment: In your specific example you don't even need the index, just use the FOR to cycle all items captured.
But yes, this would work.

Comment: Thank you @ClaudioBatista for your reply. I tried but it didn't work. It only printed out 1 line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your question is, you have similar kind of xpath around 20 times in the webpage. If my understanding is correct, you should use the **Get Webelements** keyword from Selenium Library.

```
@{product}     Get Webelements    //div[contains(@class,'ProductCard__TitleMaxLines')]
```

The above line will create the list of webelements which having the same xpath

Comment: Yes! That's what I wanted. GetWebelements works, thank you so much Roby.

Comment: Hi @SylvesterKruin, where should I click to accept?

Comment: @SylvesterKruin done. Thanks again.